# Presenting list of steps

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I am working on Windows 8 application in C#/XAML.

I have a list of steps to show and the list can have one to many steps.

I have tried the `GridView` and `ListView` controls, but with those, it is not possible to have each element have its own height (because one step might have only one line of text, and the next one 3 lines, for example). The `VariableSizedGridview` does not help either.

What I am trying to achieve is something like the way cooking steps are shown in the Microsoft Bing Food & Drink app. So, steps are shown in rows in the first column, and when the end of the page is reached, it creates a second column, and so on. Like so :
[image: Bing Food & Drink]

Could anyone please help me find a way to achieve this?

What control to use and how?

It looks very simple, but I was not able to find any solution while searching online.

Thank you

Here is what I have done with the `Gridview` control (the `Listview` was quite similar) :

```
<Grid Name="gridSteps" Grid.Column="3" Margin="25,69,25,69">
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                   <TextBlock Text="ÉTAPES" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                   <GridView Grid.Row="1" Name="gvGroupSteps" SelectionMode="None" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Width="400">
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Order}" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="20" Foreground="Bisque"></TextBlock>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                      </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                      <GridView.GroupStyle>
                         <GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                  <StackPanel Background="#FFC9C9C9">
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>
                                  </StackPanel>
                               </DataTemplate>
                            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                         </GroupStyle>
                      </GridView.GroupStyle>

                   </GridView>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking all over the internet for a solution, but could not manage to find anything.
So i decided to do everything myself in C# code.

In short, in have a StackPanel with Orientation set to Horizontal, and I add a Grid to it and add rows to that Grid for every item i have. When the maximum height is reached (based on the screen Height), I add a new Grid to the StackPanel, and so on.

Here is my code if anyone needs it :

```
// Nombre de lignes maximal (16 lignes à 1080p)
         int maxCharCount = (int)Window.Current.Bounds.Height * 16 / 1080;

         spIngredients.Children.Clear();
         foreach (var groupIngredient in db.Table<GroupIngredient>().Where(x => x.RecipeId == _currentRecipe.Id))
         {
            int linesCount = 0;
            int row = 0;
            var gGroup = new Grid();
            spIngredients.Children.Add(gGroup);
            gGroup.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

            var groupName = new TextBlock() { Text = groupIngredient.Name, FontSize = 20, FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold, Margin = new Thickness(10) };
            gGroup.Children.Add(groupName);
            Grid.SetRow(groupName, row);

            foreach (var ingredient in db.Table<Ingredient>().Where(x => x.GroupIngredientId == groupIngredient.Id))
            {
               // Nombre de lignes, split à 45 char
               linesCount += 1 + ingredient.IngredientFull.Length / 45;

               if (linesCount >= maxCharCount)
               {
                  var gCol = new Grid();
                  spIngredients.Children.Add(gCol);
                  gCol.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                  var col = new TextBlock() { Text = "", FontSize = 20, FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold, Margin = new Thickness(10) };
                  gCol.Children.Add(col);
                  gGroup = gCol;

                  row = 0;
                  linesCount = 0;
                  Grid.SetRow(col, row);
               }

               row++;
               ingredient.Quantity = ingredient.Quantity * multiplier;

               gGroup.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

               var ingredientName = new TextBlock() { Text = ingredient.IngredientFull, Margin = new Thickness(10), FontSize = 18, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap, MaxWidth = 300 };
               gGroup.Children.Add(ingredientName);
               Grid.SetRow(ingredientName, row);
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post the XAML that you have tried.  It sounds like to me that you need to nest your view items.  Consider this very simple example:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>  
<ListView>
<ListViewItem>Step 1</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem>
<ListView>
<ListViewItem>Step 1a</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem>Step 1b</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem>Step 1c</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
</ListViewItem>
<ListViewItem>Step 2</ListViewItem>
</ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried the GridView and ListView controls, but with those, it is not possible to have each element have its own height

My recollection is that you can in fact have elements with different heights using those controls. These are both types of `ItemsControl`, which supports data templating, which in turn allows you to customize the appearance of each item, including its height.

That said, you may find that the simpler `ListBox` suits your needs in this case. It's hard to say without a code example or other details.

You should read MSDN's [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a thorough discussion of the whole process, along with some good examples of what you can do. Pay particular attention to the section named "Choosing a DataTemplate Based on Properties of the Data Object". While a single template could still have variable height, clearly by using a different template according to your specific needs you can customize each item's style to your heart's content.

If this does not address your question, please provide a more detailed question. You should include [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, explaining precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you, i will go read. And I just added some code sample.

Comment: The problem with `Listview` and `Gridview` is that even if i try to set the Height of each element independently, the height applies to all items. So if my last item has a Height of 100, every other item will have their height set to 100. I can use the RowSpan property, but it is not really what i want to do.
As for the `Listbox` control, it does not allow dynamic columns when the maximum height is reached, so i don't think i would use that.